# Windows 8 metro apps assign button style programmatically C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to set style to button programmatically in C#, i tried it but not done it, i set style to button in XAML so its working fine. But in C# programmatically m not sure how to do it..

In XAML i did like this

```
Style="{StaticResource DefaultMusicButtonStyle}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
testButton.Style = Resources["DefaultMusicButtonStyle"] as Style;
```